# Can I use article template that exist in MikTeX or TexLive?

Tags: packages, miktex, texlive, document-classes

OK, the question is simple and perhaps a bit silly, but I cannot find an exact answer so here it is:

I'm writing an article for a journal which has recommended article class, say `elsarticle`. The template exists in TeX repo such as **MikTeX** or **TexLive**, and can be downloaded.

Then I realize that I cannot do something like

```
\usepackage{elsarticle}
\documentclass{cas-sc}
```

because I cannot put `\usepackage{}` before `\documentclass{}`.

So, do I have to manually download that template which contains the `.cls` file, and place it in the same folder where I write the article?

I cannot directly use it from my `main.tex` file, correct?

Comment: your question hard to understand. `elsarticle` is  class not a package and is already in texlive so you do not need extra files just `\documentclass{elsarticle}`

Comment: When David Carlisle's comment and my answer were submitted you had not figured out your problem. --- GOM

Comment: please do not edit answers into the question, it breaks the question and answer format of the site and confuses later readers. If as here, an answer solves the question, you can accept the answer, or you can post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 5):

`elsearticle` is a class not a package.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%%% maybe some packages
\begin{document}
```

Comment: OK. I figured it out. I don't need to \usepackage{elsarticle}. It seems once I downloaded it in the miktex-console, I can directly use it.

Comment: I thought that that was my answer.